react-native version 0.75.3 , react - native firebase version is 20.4.0 and xcode version is 16
While running in react-native ios project after configuration of Google-PlayServices.json file i got error is
While Running react-native 0.75.3 latest application after installing react-native firebase/app how to fix above issue -G' for Target 'arm64-apple-ios13.4-simulator' in BoringSSL-GRPC Build"
How to fix
I want to run my code with latest react-native configuration along with firebase
